# How do you exclude an object from picking up the default Resource Dictionary?

Tags: wpf, resources

I am using a 3rd party resource dictionary and it is conflicting with another usercontrol that I need to use.  How do I exclude this usercontrol from picking up the default resource dictionary?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont know if you can explicity exclude it but you could create your own resource dictionary and create a style for your control within it.

Reference the style specifically with a key and use that key for you user control. Should override the default resource dictionary. You may have to merge resource dictionaries into a [shared resource](http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2007/06/08/defining-and-using-shared-resources-in-a-custom-control-library.aspx).